# how do i show bit length of a byte, NOT Integer

Tags: binary, byte, bit

#Python 3+

i read bin byte
ReadSize =1

with open(ArgsFile, "rb") as f:
byte = f.read(ReadSize)
print(byte)

example output
'h'

to show Pos integer i would write
print(len(bin(1)[2:]))
or neg int
len(bin(-1)[3:])

how do I print length of bits needed for my byte read from file?

Comment: A byte is always 8-bits in Python. The number of bits to represent a byte is then always 8. Perhaps the question might be "What is the minimum number of bits to represent a positive integer"? (Or may not; in any case, the question is not very clear.)

Comment: If the 'question might be' above is correct, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12349498/2864740 contains useful information. If the number can be negative (and thus probably assumed to be two's complement), the answer changes slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**Test file:**

```
$ hexdump -C ~/test.bin 
00000000  b1 23 50 c2 06                                    |.#P..|
00000005
```

**test.py:**

```
import sys


def main():
    with open("test.bin", "rb") as f:
        while b := f.read(1):
            bits = int.from_bytes(b, sys.byteorder).bit_length()
            print(b.hex(), bits)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
b1 8
23 6
50 7
c2 8
06 3
```